# Is this a good way to hide my ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to programmatically hide my Action Bar in Android once 2 seconds have passed.

The action bar can show up once again if the user taps the top of the screen.

I looked around and found a variety of methods to hide the action bar using different themes.

However, my method goes like this:

```
private void hideActionBar(){
    if(getSupportActionBar().isShowing()){
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
}
```

As a result, there's an animation pulling up the action bar along with the entire screen.

Is this supposed to work like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to hide the toolbar I treat it like another View:

```
public void setToolbarVisible(boolean visible) {
    mToolbar.setVisibility(visible
        ? View.VISIBLE
        : View.GONE);
}
```

And this have no animation. Otherwise your code is perfectly fine.

Edit: make sure you don't have `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in your ActionBar's parent layout because that can be more likely the root of the animation problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and disable the hide animation like this:

```
try
{
  getSupportActionBar().getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setShowHideAnimationEnabled", boolean.class).invoke(getSupportActionBar(), false);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
  // The animation will still be displayed if an exception was thrown.
}
```

Unfortunately there is no easy way to disable the animation as it is hard-coded in the implementation.